# Prevent application from gaining root access

Tags: applications, root-access

I'm developing a device management application on a rooted device and I'm looking for a solution to the problem that any application can access the su commands a get access to change things on the device. I want to restrict that and only let my app use the su commands and block it to the other applications including applications that will be installed by the user(if the user installs an application it will be blocked from root access automatically). Any solutions?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatical solution or an end-user solution?

Comment: preferably programmatic , but maybe end-user solution would fit too. I'm looking for all options available

Comment: Magisk Hide does what you need, by making use of bind mounts and mount namespaces.

Comment: what are those "bind mounts" and "bind namespaces" ? can I do the same thing Magisk do in my application ? I prefer for some reasons to not install any other application on the device unless it's totally necessary

Comment: As I understand you would need to make app that deals with what app is granted root access because you can't force one app to do what other app said, anyway you would need to force users to use that app which manages root and app you were making in first place.. I think it would be more appropriate to post this question to programming related community, here they don't do software development questions.

Comment: @OfekRegev [magiskhide](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/native/jni/magiskhide/proc_monitor.cpp), [bind mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), [mount namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html)